# Increment value in JSON file on server on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a counter. It gets value from JSON file, saved on server. And this part works nice.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var users = (function () {
    var users = null;
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': 'http://toriya8.ru/new-year/users.json',
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
            users = data.users_value;
        }
    });
    return users;
})();
    $('#counter-number').text(users*=1000);
});
```

But i want to increment users_value on click. (It's gonna be on form send in the future). 
 I tried this:

```
$('.counter').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://toriya8.ru/new-year/users.json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {increment: true},
      success: function() { console.log('Request has returned') }
  });
});
```

And this :

```
$('.counter').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://toriya8.ru/new-year/users.json',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
        data.users_value += 1;
        console.log('Request has returned')
      }
  });
});
```

Both fires console message, but doesn't change data in JSON file.

Here is my users.json file :

```
{
  "users_value" : 3
}
```

P.S. Find a lot info on Stackoverflow, but nothing really helped.

Comment: You need to use server side code to update JSON file. You can't do it by just using client side code

Comment: Do you have php on server side?

Comment: No, in fact i just discovered, that i need it. And now i need help even more)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally found an answer. Really i totally forgot about server side.
This is a solution:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var users = (function () {
    var users = null;
    $.ajax({
      'async': false,
      'global': false,
      'url': 'http://toriya8.ru/new-year/users.json',
      'dataType': "json",
      'success': function (data) {
        users = data.users_value;
      }
    });
    return users;
  })();
  $('#counter-number').text(users*=1000);

  $('.counter').click(function() {
    $.post("parser.php",{ajax: true});
  });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$jsonString = file_get_contents('users.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

$data['users_value'] += 1;

$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('users.json', $newJsonString);
?>
```

And JSON :

```
{
  "users_value" : 3
}
```